# Trying to create a generic Kafka consumer factory

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm trying to implement a generic Kafka consumer factory. By generic I mean that the factory will receive generics K,V that will indicate the types of the key and the value of the consumed message.

```
public class KafkaConsumerFactory<K, V> {
    private Properties properties;
```

In my constructor I'm calling a method that responsible for validating that the generics K,V are compatible with the deseralization classes :

```
    public KafkaConsumerFactory(Properties p) {
       ....
       ....
       validateGenericsWithDeserializationProperties();
}
```

The relevant function :

```
private void validateGenericsWithDeserializationProperties() throws Exception {
    try {
        String keyDeserializerClass = (String) (this.properties.get(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG));
        String valueDeserializerClass = (String) (this.properties.get(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG));
        Deserializer<K> keyDeserializer = (Deserializer<K>) Class.forName(keyDeserializerClass).getConstructor().newInstance();
        Deserializer<V> valueDeserializer = (Deserializer<V>) Class.forName(valueDeserializerClass ).getConstructor().newInstance();
        System.out.println(keyDeserializer.toString());
        System.out.println(valueDeserializer.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("There is an incompatibility with the deserialization parameters in the properties with the generics <K,V>");
    }

}
```

But it seems that when I pass generics K,V that aren't compatible with the deserializer class the code doesn't throw exception , for example:

```
K=String,
V=Long,
key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

I was expecting an exception on the downcasting on the following lines :

```
    Deserializer<K> keyDeserializer = (Deserializer<K>)(Class.forName(keyDeserializerClass).getConstructor().newInstance());
    Deserializer<V> valueDeserializer = (Deserializer<V>)Class.forName(valueDeserializerClass).getConstructor().newInstance();
```

I understand that those lines won't throw exception because of erasure of generic types.

Is there any other way to check for incompatibility between the deserialization class to the type of generic before trying to consume data?

Comment: Where do you expect an exception exactly? Do you know about "type erasure"?

Comment: I updated the post. I understand type erasure it means that K,V are replaced by the real types before runtime and we wont have any info on K,V during real time. However, I expect an exception to be through because the of the downcasting there..

Comment: At runtime the line basically is `Deserializer valueDeserializer = Class.forName(valueDeserializerClass).getConstructor().newInstance();` which obviously does not cause any problems. The only problem would arise if you actually use the deserializer and the argument or return types do not match.

Comment: So my only way to find incompatibility is running the deserialize method in the Deserializer class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Deserializer<K> keyDeserializer = (Deserializer<K>) Class.forName(keyDeserializerClass).getConstructor().newInstance();
    Deserializer<V> valueDeserializer = (Deserializer<V>) Class.forName(valueDeserializerClass ).getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Why do you want to explicity create Deserializer object?

1. It will automatically be created as per the one specified in the properties.
2. If you want to *verify* (make sure) the appropriate deserializer is put for the appropriate key/value type, you can take the `keyClass, valueClass` in the constructor of your `KafkaConsumerFactory`

```java
  public KafkaConsumerFactory(Properties p, Class<K> keyClass, Class<V> valueClass) {
     p.putIfAbsent("key.deserializer", getDeserializer(keyClass).getName());
     p.putIfAbsent("value.deserializer", getDeserializer(valueClass).getName());
    }
```

and then you can automatically map the `keyClass`, `valueClass` to appropriate deserializer and override them in the properties.

```
Class<Deserializer> getDeserializer(Class clazz) {
   if(Long.class.equals(clazz)) { return LongDeserializer.class; }
   else if (...)
   ...
}
```

If you want to support *new* custom deserializers, you can use an interface like `CustomDeserializer` for example that has a method called `canBeProcessed(Class clazz)` which determines if the object can be deserialized and ensure that this interface is implemented by all your custom deserializers and that the method is overriden.

If you are looking to support already existing deserializers, you can write the code to check the compatability of the deserializer with a certain class in your `KafkaConsumerFactory` itself.

Usually, serializers/deserializers are mapped to certain class(es), which means that you don't need an object to verify if it can be serialized/deserialized because the data in the object has pretty less (if not nothing) to do with the actual serialization/deserialization.

In case, if the class type information isn't enough for finding out whether it's object can be deserialized or not, the option left is to create a *dummy* object and then pass it to the `deserialize()` method. If it raises an exception, then it is invalid, not otherwise.

Comment: I want to support also a custom deserializer. I'm loading the kafka properties from file so I dont know what deserializer is going to be used. I want to make sure that the K,V generics of the Factory are compatible with the properties in the file.

Comment: Even if you support custom deserializer you can add it in the properties file, for all others, you can automatically add them, for this you can do `putIfAbsent`

Comment: Yeah I understand that I can add the custom deserializer in the properties file. I want to identify a situation where the K,V generics cant be deserialized by the deserializers in the properties file.

Comment: If you want to know the types of K,V, then you can take additional params as `Class<K>` and `Class<V>` and the rest of the verification process can be done as per your feasibility. It can most typically be a map of a specific class and its corresponding deserializer

Comment: I understand that but how can I check the compatibility between Class<K> to the deserializer that was passed in the constructor ? This is the reason I opened the post for :) I'm trying to raise an exception or log one when this situation occurs

Comment: In every deserializer that is written, may be you can include one method like, `canBeProcessed(Class clazz)` which returns `true` or `false`. This can be done by writing an interface called `CustomDeserializer` which includes the `canBeProcessed` method and ensure that all your custom deserializers implement this interface and override that method

Comment: That is a good option for new custom deserializers. What about supporting the one that are already exist? For example, check the input I used in the main post.

Comment: When you have the `keyClass` and `valueClass` with you, what other info do you need to verify if a deserializer can process it or not? Generally, deserializers are mapped to the classes they can process. If your deserializers are not written that way, then you may try passing a dummy object to the `deserialize()` and check if there is any exception

Comment: The only method of deserilizer<T> interface that I can use is T deserialize(java.lang.String topic,byte[] data). It means that I need to convery my generic V into byteArray right ? Any idea why I need the topic in the deserialize ? does it actually consumes from that topic ? If the answer is yes creating a dummy object might be problematic because I dont want to consume messages , just to validate the generics vs the deserializer.

Comment: Without data, you are only left with the `Class` object. Topic, though a parameter to `deserialize()`, usually isn't widely used in serialization/deserialization. Calling `deserialize()` manually will not consume any messages.

Comment: so basically, calling the deserialize method and catching an exception is enough to validate the compatibility between the generic and the deserializer. I'll try it out. Can you please update your comment so that I'll mark it as the answer ?

Comment: The problem is that I need to pass a class as generic and not all clases have default constructor. As a result I'm getting the following exception (for type byte[] for example) : java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [B.<init>()
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349) ~[na:na]           
  in the following line of code :             keyDeserializer.deserialize("", SerializationUtils.serialize(keyClass.getConstructor().newInstance()));